# jQuery alert after 100 pixels scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to fire an alert after a user scrolls 100 pixels.

Here's what I have so far but I know I'm missing something;

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (document.documentElement.clientHeight + 
        $(document).scrollTop() == "100px")
    { 
        alert("You've scrolled 100 pixels.");
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the result of this code?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Look at the window .scrollTop (returns an integer):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 100) { // this refers to window
        alert("You've scrolled 100 pixels.");
    }
});
```

but if you have scrolled 102px it wont trigger the alert box.

if you just want to trigger the alert once have a global variable that sets to true if it has been trigged:

```
$(function(){
    var hasBeenTrigged = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100 && !hasBeenTrigged) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTrigged is set to false.
            alert("You've scrolled 100 pixels.");
            hasBeenTrigged = true;
        }
    });
});
```

or just unbind the scroll event once the alert box has been trigged:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).bind("scroll.alert", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.scrollTop() >= 100) {
            alert("You've scrolled 100 pixels.");
            $this.unbind("scroll.alert");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Would it be better to use $(this).scrollTop() >= 100 then?

Comment: Depends, if he just want it to be trigged on the exact number then its correct. I have edited that and added another example also.

Comment: you can use jQuery's [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function which automagically unbinds the event after the first call

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/ triggers only once, and if its not >= 100px it will never trigger so I don't think thats a good idea

Comment: @voigtan hmm. i haven't thought of that like that :D

Comment: Btw, `scrollTop` is a property of the jquery object, not of the `window`  object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).scrollTop() >= 100) {
    // ...
}
```

[`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) returns an integer. This version will evaluate to true once you have scrolled *past* 100px, which might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight + $(document).scrollTop() == 100
```