# How to alert when scroll page every 200px;

Tags: javascript

How to alert when scroll page every  200px;

i want to alert some text when user sceoll page every 200px; how can i do that?

i try like this but not work

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop()%200 != '0') {
                alert($(window).scrollTop());
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery alert after 100 pixels scrolled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375018/jquery-alert-after-100-pixels-scrolled)

Comment: Please define "does not work".

Comment: no duplicate, for me , i want to alert every 200px; mean alert when scroll 200,400,600,800,.... px

Comment: You'll find quite quickly that checking for exact values won't work well here, as it's very unlikely that a user will scroll to _exactly_ modulo 200. You'll probably want to employ some rounding in either direction.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kumeqijigata/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check like this:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() % 200 == 0) {
    alert($(window).scrollTop());
}
```

Comment: this breaks though as soon as the user scrolls using the scrollbar or the middle mouse button: http://jsfiddle.net/L76nzcbz/ a better approach would be to keep track of the previous scroll position and check whether there are multiples of 200 between that and the current one: http://jsfiddle.net/L76nzcbz/1/