# window.scroll is not working in my case using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make alert, when scroll is greater than or equal to 100.

I am using asp.net mvc framework. Now I have **_Layout.cshtml** and **mobile.cshtml**

the **mobile.cshtml** page will render inside of **_Layout.cshtml**. Now I write the below colde inside **mobile.cshtml** page on **head tag**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Mobile";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<head>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script>
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        alert('windows loaded');    // this alert is working
        
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= 100) {
            alert("Test");   // this alert is also working.bcz window height is greater than 100
        }


        //below all the alerts are not working

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            alert('ddd');
        });

        $(window).on('scroll',function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= 100) {
                alert("END!" + $(window).scrollTop());
            }
        });

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= 100) {
                alert("END!" + $(window).scrollTop());
            }
        });

        $(function () {
            var hasBeenTrigged = false;
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100 && !hasBeenTrigged) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTrigged is set to false.
                    alert("You've scrolled 100 pixels.");
                    hasBeenTrigged = true;
                }
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $(window).bind("scroll.alert", function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.scrollTop() >= 100) {
                    alert("You've scrolled 100 pixels.");
                    $this.unbind("scroll.alert");
                }
            });
        });
    })
    
</script>    
</head>
```

Also, there is no error message on the console

I check the answer from this [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9375065)

**UPDATE**

> I have removed all of my css file from both **_Layout.cshtml** and **mobile.cshtml** page, then it **WORKS**
>
> When I add one of the css file `<link href="~/Content/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />` from **_Layout.cshtml** page again, then it doesn't work.
>
> Remember, this css file **Material Design Lite** file. It is like bootstrap. I must use this file on my design

Comment: Can you please try switching your main window.onload with document.ready..

Comment: @Liam: This may happen for some properties in your css. Do you have a CSS file?

Comment: @bestinamir why would that matter? load comes later so should not matter.

Comment: @js__ yes, I have. I will remove it and check it out now

Comment: console.log() is better than alerts for testing

Comment: Is the body not scrollable and another element is?

Comment: @bestinamir I tried with `document.ready` alot. it doesn't work for me. I don't know why

Comment: Can you show your `_Layout.cshtml`? I'm interested where your `@RenderBody()` is since your **mobile.cshtml** has `<head>` tags. If there are 2 head tags, the html won't work, and the scripts won't work either

Comment: @Liam: Remove your `overflow: auto;` from CSS..if you have that property present in CSS.

Comment: @Liam: Or else, check with `height: 100%` , it also causes problem sometimes.

Comment: @js__ you are correct. After I removed all of my **css** file, it works. But I must use those css file.

Comment: @Liam: you don't need to remove all of the `css` , put `overflow: scroll` and try it..if it works then it's well and good!

Comment: @js__ Do you want me to replace with `scroll`?. But I can see `Overflow: hidden` only that `material.css` file. Can you please read my update

Comment: @Liam: Just saw your update..hmm.... Wait may be I can suggest you something..

Comment: @js__ The problem is only with that css file. Not in any other css file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an open issue in [this](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/5075) Github thread for **Material Design Lite** or **MDL** and it's clashes with the `scroll` event!

There is a suggestion / hack mentioned [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/5075) for this, you can try it, or else you can use [Material Components Web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web).

**MDL** is no longer maintained. Work internally has shifted to `Material Components for Web` which evolved from the `MDL v2` efforts. So, best to try and convert to that if you can for ongoing maintenance and support.